# Swift - Как остановить таймер?

Tags: swift, uikit

Как остановить таймер?

```swift
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { _ in
    if self.progressView.progress != 0 {
        self.progressView.progress -= 0.01
    } else {
        self.present(alertTimeIsOut, animated: true)
        // stop timer ???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так, например:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { timer in
    if self.progressView.progress != 0 {
        self.progressView.progress -= 0.01
    } else {
        self.present(alertTimeIsOut, animated: true)
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```